# Notepad++ remove carriage return between two words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some text in a file e.g

```
CREATE
   INDEX TST_NK ON TST.TEST_DIM
  (
    TSL_ID
   )
    DEFER NO ;
CREATE
   INDEX TST_NK ON TST.TEST_DIM
  (
    TSL_ID,
     DES_ID
   )
    DEFER NO ;
```

I want to remove all return characters between CREATE and ;

In notepad++ i'm able to search this text using regex CREATE\b(.+?); however i'm not sure how to replace the return characters in this text so that i can have all the create statements in single line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find what:

```
(?<=[^\s;])\s*\n\s*
```

Replace with: (single space)

Then hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

It will search for any sequence of space character, where there is at least one new line character for replacement. The look-behind is used to make sure that there is no `;` in front of such sequence.

Comment: Amazing, it worked... Thanks a lot. Just waiting for the system to allow me to accept this answer :-)